# Compiling stressapptest on NDK for Android

Tags: android, android-ndk, ndk-build

I am currently working on trying to compile the stressapptest (link: https://github.com/stressapptest/stressapptest) using the NDK environment, and for some reason, I'm having a hard time. These are the steps that I have taken:

1. Clone the repository onto my computer
2. Added a jni folder and moved all the files into it
3. Created an Application.mk file
4. Opened PowerShell from the location of my jni folder and execute ndk-build. This is the error I'm getting:

   ```
   PS C:\Users\...\Desktop\stressapptest-master\stressapptest-master> ndk-build    
   Android NDK: APP_PLATFORM not set. Defaulting to minimum supported version android-16.    
   [arm64-v8a] Compile++      : stressapptest <= main.cc
   In file included from jni/src/main.cc:17:
   jni/src/sattypes.h:25:10: fatal error: 'algorithm' file not found        
   #include <algorithm>
            ^~~~~~~~~~~
   1 error generated.
   make: *** [obj/local/arm64-v8a/objs/stressapptest/src/main.o] Error 1
   ```

Is there anything else that I need in order to compile this to run on an Android system?

Answer (score 0):

Set `APP_STL` to `c++_shared` in your Application.mk. ndk-build does not use any STL by default.

Comment: I had actually figured this out last night just before heading out from work. I did what you said here, as well as set APP_ABI to armeabi-v7a.

Comment: So this worked or didn't work? If it worked you should mark it as the correct answer.